# Using super methods in Javascript based on Crockford's functional inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I've been reading the chapter on functional inheritance in Crockford's 'The Good Parts'. In the mammal example he gives I'm a bit confused as to why he uses the `superior` method to modify the `get_name` function. Here is the example in question:

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
    this.prototype[name] = func;
    return this;
};

var mammal = function (spec) {
    var that = {};

    that.get_name = function () {
        return spec.name;
    };

    that.says = function () {
        return spec.saying || '';
    };

    return that;
};

var myMammal = mammal({
    name: 'Herb'
});

var cat = function (spec) {
    spec.saying = spec.saying || 'meow';
    var that = mammal(spec);

    that.purr = function (n) {
        var i, s = '';
        for (i = 0; i < n; i += 1) {
            if (s) {
                s += '-';
            }
            s += 'r';
        }
        return s;
    };

    that.get_name = function () {
        return that.says() + ' ' + spec.name + ' ' + that.says();
    };

    return that;
};

Object.method('superior', function (name) {
    var that = this,
        method = that[name];
    return function () {
        return method.apply(that, arguments);
    };
});

var coolcat = function (spec) {
    var that = cat(spec);
    var super_get_name = that.superior('get_name');

    that.get_name = function (n) {
        return 'like ' + super_get_name() + ' baby';
    };
    return that;
};

var myCoolCat = coolcat({
    name: 'Bix'
});

var name = myCoolCat.get_name(); // 'like meow Bix meow baby'
```

I'm confused about this because I can replicate the same thing by removing the `superior` method and just changing `coolcat` as follows:

```
var coolcat = function(spec) {
    var that = cat(spec);
    var super_get_name = that.get_name();

    that.get_name = function(n) {
        return 'like ' + super_get_name + ' baby';
    };
    return that;
};
```

So, I don't understand why Crockford chooses to use the `superior` method. Is anyone able to explain at all?

Comment: Wow, is Crockford really suggesting doing this? It's a misguided not-very-readable way to get superclass method calls IMO. To avoid using the real language feature of prototype inheritance that hard, and then to spoil it all by prototyping onto `Object` of all things? Ouch.

Comment: @bobince: That code doesn't prototype onto `Object`; rather, it prototypes onto `Function`, which makes it available on `Object` (since `Object` is a constructor-function). (Though I must admit, I'm also pretty surprised by this suggestion. It seems like it would be clearer to write `var super_get_name = that.get_name`. That would force the new `get_name` to write `super_get_name.apply(that)` instead of just `super_get_name()`, but that doesn't seem like a big deal to me.)

Comment: @ruakh: The call to `method()` is adding the member `superior` onto `Object.prototype`.

Comment: @bobince: Oh, yes, you're right. O.K., yeah, that's pretty terrible. :-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea here is that this:

```
var super_get_name = that.superior('get_name');
```

makes `super_get_name` into a function that — every time it is called — invokes `that`'s *original* `get_name` method. This allows the *new* `get_name` to call the *old* (super-class) `get_name`.

Now, if the original `get_name` method will never have any effect other than to return a single value that never changes, then yeah, this is kind of pointless; you can just save that single-value-that-never-changes and then use it in the new `get_name`. But if the original `get_name` can actually do things (such as, say, run an AJAX request, or change the styling of an HTML element), or if its return-value can change (say, if there were some corresponding `set_name` method), then there would be an important difference between what your code does (save the original return-value and use it) and what Crockford's code does (save the original method and invoke it).

Comment: thanks for your response. I'm still a bit confused. If I write `var super_get_name = that.get_name()` won't I be getting the latest return value anyway? So, why does it matter that the new `get_name` can call the old `get_name`?

Comment: @StephenYoung: If you write `var super_get_name = that.get_name()`, then the old `get_name()` will be called when you originally create the `coolcat`, and will *not* be called when you later call `myCoolcat.get_name()`. So `myCoolcat.get_name()` won't have the *latest* return-value, but rather, the *original* return-value.

Answer (score 3):

The confusion that arises from this chapter of Crockford's book arises as what Crockford describes is "his" preferred pattern for implementing inheritance in JavaScript, which relies on his extending the `Function` object with the `Function.prototype.method` (chapter 1.3) which he uses to add methods to the Function object.

The problem addressed in the `coolcat` example is the need to access the method of the parent type. In 'classical' OO languages like Java this is natural as classes exist in their own right. In JavaScript inheritance is prototypical, you make an object of type `mammal` and then modify the object to create the type `cat` or `coolcat`.

Depending on your design you may add properties and functions or override an 'inherited' function. The problem arises when you override an 'inherited' function, in JavaScript you basically replace the old function with the new function, thereby loosing the older function.

Crockford now needs to do two things:

1. get the parent's (cat's) `get_name` method; and
2. save it in a manner that can be used from within the overridden method.

In this code:

```
var coolcat = function(spec) {
    var that = cat(spec), 
        super_get_name = that.superior('get_name');
    that.get_name = function(n) {
        return 'like ' + super_get_name() + ' baby';
    };
    return that;
};
```

He does 1. by calling the superior method to get a function that gets the cat's `get_name` function; 
and he does 2. by saving it to the `super_get_name` variable within the coolcat function(/object) allowing access to the cat's `get_name` function before it is overridden (more correctly overwritten) by the coolcat's `get_name` function.

In my opinion the confusion arises because:

1. The `superior` method is named oddly: the 'superior' method is simply a **function look up by name** method and could be better named, for example as `getFunctionByName` (you can try this by replacing the string `get_name`, by `purr`, the coolcat's get_name will now call purr, just remember to call it as `super_get_name(10)` otherwise you'll get an empty string back).
2. Secondly the code and the pattern obfuscates the code by relying on some particular Crockford patterns, and is likely to stresses you out if you attempt to dive into this chapter without having followed the entire book.

I think there is a simpler way to achieve this, one that I think because it is completely localized is easier to understand etc., as in the code below:

```
var coolcat = function(spec) {
    var that = cat(spec);
    that.parent_get_name = that.get_name;
    that.get_name = function() {
       return 'like ' + this.parent_get_name() + ' baby';
    };
    return that;
};
```

There are some other oddities for example the argument `n` in definition of the `coolcat get_name` function, which I can only assume came from copying the purr function, which would suggest a ghost writer!

Finally, I would suggest that before one reads the book one should listen to his talk on 'JavaScript the good parts'. The talk is absolutely brilliant, much better than the book.