# Cannot found the parent class method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oop

Here is the parent class:

```
    export default class RosterTableUtil{
    constructor() {
        let highLightCellIndex = -1, highLightRowIndex = -1;
        ................
        this.updateUI = (cellIndex, rowIndex) => {
            highLightCellIndex = cellIndex;
            highLightRowIndex = rowIndex;
        }
      }
   }
```

Here is the child class:

```
import RosterTableUtil from "./RosterTableUtil";
export default class RosterSchedulerTableUtil extends RosterTableUtil{
  constructor(){
    super();
    .............

    this.updateUI = (cellIndex, rowIndex) => {
        super.updateUI(cellIndex, rowIndex);
        updateSelectRegion(cellIndex, rowIndex);
    }  
  }
}
```

When the RosterSchedulerTableUtil.updateUI function is called, I got the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).updateUI is not a function
```

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42036349/uncaught-typeerror-intermediate-value-is-not-a-function

Comment: you need define updateUI in class body instead of in constructor

Comment: @JASBIRSINGH That's totally unrelated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated to use [private fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields#private_fields).

It's not obvious to me why you'd want to do all of that within the constructor. Seems like that's what instance methods are for. You could move it out of the constructor like this:

```js
class RosterTableUtil {
  #highLightCellIndex = -1
  #highLightRowIndex = -1;
  
  updateUI (cellIndex, rowIndex) {
    this.#highLightCellIndex = cellIndex;
    this.#highLightRowIndex = rowIndex;
    console.log(`RosterTableUtil row ${this.#highLightRowIndex}, cell ${this.#highLightCellIndex}`);
  }
}

class RosterSchedulerTableUtil extends RosterTableUtil {
  updateUI (cellIndex, rowIndex) {
    super.updateUI(cellIndex, rowIndex);
    // do other stuff
  }
}

const util = new RosterSchedulerTableUtil();
util.updateUI(1,2);
util.updateUI(3,4);
```

Comment: I want to make all variables to be private, so I put everything in the constructor.

Comment: @TheKNVB Then you should use private fields, or not use `class` syntax at all

Comment: What should I use? function?

Comment: Updated answer to use [private fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields#private_fields) (and removed the constructor altogether because it's not needed for this example).

Comment: @TheKNVB Yes, you'd use a plain object-returning `function`, and [parasitic inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649077/using-super-methods-in-javascript-based-on-crockfords-functional-inheritance) instead of the `super` keyword

Answer (score -1):

To fix the problem, you need to add a super() call to the beginning of the updateUI function in the child class.

```
export default class RosterSchedulerTableUtil extends RosterTableUtil {

  constructor() {

    super();
    // Additional constructor logic for the child class
  }

  updateUI(cellIndex, rowIndex) {

    super.updateUI(cellIndex, rowIndex); // Call the parent class method
    updateSelectRegion(cellIndex, rowIndex);

  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this one, the error message is :
`RosterSchedulerTableUtil.js:163 Uncaught ReferenceError: Super constructor may only be called once`

Comment: super call in the constructor first then use it.

Comment: I have called super() in the constructor.

Comment: try to call the function by this.
this.updateUI(cellIndex, rowIndex);